# (python) Some trouble with RE's and .txt formatting

Tags: python, regex, string

Bit of a noob here. The task at hand is to parse a .txt file for certain strings. I am using RE's to help with this, but this line is not working:

```
s = 'Qty'
for line in txtdoc:
    if s in line:
        quantity = re.search(':[1-9]', line)
        print(quantity.group())
```

And the text to be parsed (from a line in my txtdoc file):

```
stringstringQty:1stringstring
```

Am I correct that I should see ':1' printed? Instead it gives an error because "quantity" variable is empty. I have also tried to use re.findall and it just printed an empty set "[ ]".

Now, I am thinking this may have to do with the *formatting* of the .txt file, because nominally the data I need is in MS Word. I have a script that saves the Word doc as .txt and then I try to parse that.

When I take the line that I'm trying to parse here and COPY/PASTE it to Outlook, or MS Word, it formats like this automatically:

```
string
string
Qty:
1
string
string
```

So after seeing that, I tried

```
re.search(r':/n[1:9]', line)
```

But that didn't work either. Any ideas? I'd provide more of my code but I was working on this at work and have been thinking about it since I got home, so I had to go off of memory.

Comment: Are you just wanting the number?

Comment: Are you reading parts of the string in different iterations? Is there a newline separating the strings?

Comment: @hwnd Lol... Yes, sorry. Should be simple enough, no? The reason I don't search for '[1-9]' is because there are actually a few other digits scattered throughout the string.

Comment: What do you mean by `"quantity" variable is empty`? What's the exact error message?

Comment: @perreal Might be. My script saves the .doc directly into .txt, and the formatting seems to be a little weird, despite all of the text being there.

Comment: It looks like it's a problem with the input format. You'll probably want to process that better. You might have lone `\r` characters or other weird crap in there.

Comment: @user2357112 is there an easy way to port the .doc text into .txt and strip all formatting out? So it's just lines of text and nothing else? I had though that just turning it into a Notepad text file would do that automatically, but I guess not..

Comment: You need to see what's actually in the file, instead of guessing. For example, you could just `read()` the file in Python, then `print(repr(s))`, which will show you all the invisible characters, etc. (However, if you can generate a proper text file in the first place, instead of trying to use a doc as a text file, that will obviously be easier.)

Comment: @abarnert I have a database of .doc files, and the information I'm pulling comes from them. So I have to get it out of there one way or another.

Comment: @griffsterb: If they're modern (DOCX) .doc files, those can be parsed pretty easily in Python. If they're old-style .doc files, your best bet is probably to use something like [antiword](http://www.winfield.demon.nl) to extract the text, instead of trying to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have a Word .doc file, not a text file.

A Word file is essentially a sequence of runs of formatted text. (It's actually more complicated than that, it's a tree of all kinds of things, some of which are runs of text, but let's keep it simple for now.)

In "classic" Word format, each of these runs is a string of bytes. In modern (DOCX, aka Office 2007, aka Office Open XML, aka WordML) Word format, each of them is an XML node in a tree. But either way, if you have one run that ends with `:` and another that starts with `1`, you won't found `:1` in the file; you'll find `:` followed by a bunch of cruft (the end of one binary object and the start of the next, or the end of one XML node and the start of the next, possibly with other objects/nodes in between), followed by the `1`.

There's no good way to deal with this without actually parsing the Word format.

So, the big question is, which format do you have?

---

If it's DOCX, that's basically just an XML file, or a ZIP file with XML files inside of it, which you can parse natively in Python—or, better, use a module like [`docx`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/docx/0.2.1) that does all the hard work for you.

If it's classic DOC, the only way to parse it is to read the reverse-engineered documentation that people have written up over the years and write some nasty code to deal with it. Or, of course, you can use some code that someone's already written. In this case, I don't know of any python modules that will help, but you can control the [`antiword`](http://www.winfield.demon.nl) program pretty easily via `subprocess`.

---

Or, alternatively, if you have a program that can read the files on your machine, like Word or Wordpad/Write on Windows, or iWork Pages on Mac, or OpenOffice.org/Libre Office on any platform, you can script that. Python has nice wrappers to talk to COM interfaces on Windows and AppleScript interfaces on Mac, and OO.o/Libre is built to be scriptable.

[This blog post](http://www.galalaly.me/index.php/2011/09/use-python-to-parse-microsoft-word-documents-using-pywin32-library/) is a nice example of using Word on Windows via `pywin32` to do things to doc files. You can use this as a starting point for your own code to extract the text from each file, or to make Word to the searching for you, or to just save a plain text copy of each file which you can then do whatever you want with. There are hundreds of other such examples all over the web, as well as similar examples for using `appscript` or `ScriptingBridge` to do the equivalent on the Mac, or using VBA instead of Python to script from inside Word, etc. To find out what functions are available when scripting Word, see the [Word 2013 developer reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee861527.aspx), or the similar docs for earlier versions if you don't have 2013, or just "Open Dictionary" in AppleScript Editor and look at Word's dictionary if you have a Mac.

Comment: Ah. This is a very comprehensive answer. Thank you. My files are all .doc. I am using the newest version of Word so it is possible to save them as .docx, not sure why I wasn't doing that from the beginning. Anyway, I will see if there is an easy way to change all of the extensions to docx. Would parsing the files as .txt work properly with .docx? Or do I basically need to start over regardless? I encountered the docx module early on but struggled with it because there was not much documentation.

Comment: @griffsterb: No, you can't parse .docx files as .doc; you have the same problem, except that the runs of text are inside XML nodes instead of binary objects. The only advantage is that XML is easy to parse in Python (and there are modules that already do that specifically for docx), while undocumented binary formats that are only incompletely reverse-engineered are not. (Also I don't _think_ you're confused about this bit, but just to make sure: just changing the extensions doesn't affect the contents of the files. What matters is what format the file is in, not what the name is.)

Comment: @griffsterb: Meanwhile, if you can get Word to save the files as DOCX files, why can't you get Word to save them as plain text files? Then your life would be easy.

Comment: @abernert I probably can save them as plain text files, I'll have to check on Monday. The problem is I have hundreds of these files already in .doc format. So unless there's some kind of tool to mass change the formats, I would need to save each one as plain text individually.

Comment: @griffsterb: You can automate Word to change all of the files for you, either using a VBA macro, or using [`pywin32`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) to talk to its COM interface from Python. (You still haven't mentioned your platform, so I'm assuming it's Windows. If it's Mac, it's the same idea but AppleScript or ScriptingBridge/appscript from Python.) Either way, there are examples all over the web that can get you started.

Comment: @abernet Sounds good, thanks for all the help. I will (try to) use docx to do most of the reading/writing for me. Unfortunately I am having problems getting it to install but that is another story. Also I am on Windows w/ python 3.3.

Comment: @griffsterb: How are you trying to install it? First, if you're trying to build manually instead of using `pip`, start using `pip`. Second, since you're on Windows, and presumably using Python 3.3 from the official Python.org installer, have you checked Christoph Gohlke's [Unofficial Windows Binaries](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) page? If there's a package you need and he doesn't have it, you can always email him and see if he'll add it.

Comment: @griffsterb: Actually, now that I look at `docx`, it's clearly not Python 3-compatible. There's a fork (by the original author) called [`python-docx`](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx) that _is_ 3.x-compatible, but it looks like it's still in pre-release status. So, if you want to go with the `docx` solution today, you may need to install Python 2.7 in parallel with 3.3.

Comment: @abernet Yeah, I went the other route and am trying to use pywin32. I have used pywin32 with Excel, but having some trouble grabbing data out of Word. I actually [posted another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20227014/pulling-data-out-of-ms-word-with-pywin32) earlier today regarding that. Thanks for your help.