# Pulling data out of MS Word with pywin32

Tags: python, ms-word, pywin32

I am running python 3.3 in Windows and I need to pull strings out of Word documents. I have been searching far and wide for about a week on the best method to do this. Originally I tried to save the .docx files as .txt and parse through using RE's, but I had some formatting problems with hidden characters - I was using a script to open a .docx and save as .txt. I am wondering if I did a proper File>SaveAs>.txt would it strip out the odd formatting and then I could properly parse through? I don't know but I gave up on this method.

I tried to use the [docx module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/docx) but I've been told it is not compatible with python 3.3. So I am left with using pywin32 and the COM. I have used this successfully with Excel to get the data I need but I am having trouble with Word because there is FAR less documentation and [reading through the object model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb244515%28v=office.12%29.aspx) on Microsoft's website is over my head.

Here is what I have so far to open the document(s):

```
import win32com.client as win32
import glob, os

word = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Word.Application')
word.Visible = True

for infile in glob.glob(os.path.join(r'mypath', '*.docx')):
    print(infile)
    doc = word.Documents.Open(infile)
```

So at this point I can do something like

```
print(doc.Content.Text)
```

And see the contents of the files, but it still looks like there is some odd formatting in there and I have no idea how to actually parse through to grab the data I need. I can create RE's that will successfully find the strings that I'm looking for, I just don't know how to implement them into the program using the COM.

The code I have so far was mostly found through Google. I don't even think this is that hard, it's just that reading through the object model on Microsoft's website is like reading a foreign language. Any help is MUCH appreciated. Thank you.

Edit: code I was using to save the files from docx to txt:

```
for path, dirs, files in os.walk(r'mypath'):
    for doc in [os.path.abspath(os.path.join(path, filename)) for filename in files if fnmatch.fnmatch(filename, '*.docx')]:
        print("processing %s" % doc)
        wordapp.Documents.Open(doc)
        docastxt = doc.rstrip('docx') + 'txt'
        wordapp.ActiveDocument.SaveAs(docastxt,FileFormat=win32com.client.constants.wdFormatText)
        wordapp.ActiveDocument.Close()
```

Comment: What about telling Word to just save each document as a plain text file (with name `os.path.splitext(infile)[0] + '.txt'`), which you can then operate on in Python? It's a little hacky, but it does mean you don't have to learn Word's complicated document model. If that's not enough to go on, I can show you some (untested, but probably-close-to-correct) code to do the save-as and you can probably take it from there.

Comment: @abernet Thanks for the suggestion. That seems to be the best way to do it. I have already pieced together some code to save the .docx files as plain text, and I verified that all the hidden formatting was gone. Since the Word files have a lot of tables, the plain text has a ton of \n, but nothing else. So now it's just a matter of iterating through each line and picking out the strings I need. Fantastic!

Comment: Two last thoughts: First, if you have any non-ASCII text, you might want to use [`wdFormatUnicodeText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb238158(v=office.12).aspx) (that is, `7`) rather than one of the encoded plain-text formats. Just remember that what Microsoft calls "Unicode" is UTF-16-LE (with BOM), so you'd need to `open(txtfile, 'utf-16')`. Second, Word always saves with DOS `\r\n` line endings (it can also do classic Mac, but not Unix, because Microsoft). So, make sure to use universal newlines when reading the files in Python.

Comment: One comment on your new version: The `Documents.open` method returns the opened `Document`. Just use that; don't rely on the fact that the newly-opened document will usually become the `ActiveDocument`.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to learn the complicated way Word models documents, and then how that's exposed through the Office object model, a much simpler solution is to have Word save a plain-text copy of the file.

There are a lot of options here. Use `tempfile` to create temporary text files and then delete them, or store permanent ones alongside the doc files for later re-use? Use Unicode (which, in Microsoft speak, means UTF-16-LE with a BOM) or encoded text? And so on. So, I'll just pick something reasonable, and you can look at the [`Document.SaveAs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb221597%28v=office.12%29.aspx), [`WdSaveFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb238158%28v=office.12%29.aspx), etc. docs to modify it.

```
wdFormatUnicodeText = 7

for infile in glob.glob(os.path.join(r'mypath', '*.docx')):
    print(infile)
    doc = word.Documents.Open(infile)
    txtpath = os.path.splitext('infile')[0] + '.txt'
    doc.SaveAs(txtpath, wdFormatUnicodeText)
    doc.Close()
    with open(txtpath, encoding='utf-16') as f:
        process_the_file(f)
```

As noted in your comments, what this does to complex things like tables, multi-column text, etc. may not be exactly what you want. In that case, you might want to consider saving as, e.g., `wdFormatFilteredHTML`, which Python has nice parsers for. (It's a lot easier to BeautifulSoup a table than to win32com-Word it.)

Comment: @abernet, I edited my original post with the code snippet I am/was using to convert docx to txt files. Would I be okay using "FileFormat=win32com.client.constants.wdFormatUnicodeText" in my code for the same result?

Comment: @griffsterb: Yes—in fact, not just OK, but better. I just used the number because in some cases (and I don't remember the details, and don't have anything to test on) COM constants don't work properly with pywin32. If they work, use them.

Answer (score 0):

[oodocx](https://github.com/evfredericksen/oodocx) is my fork of the python-docx module that is fully compatible with Python 3.3. You can use the replace method to do regular expression searches. Your code would look something like:

```
from oodocx import oodocx

d = oodocx.Docx('myfile.docx')
d.replace('searchstring', 'replacestring')
d.save('mynewfile.docx')
```

If you just want to remove strings, you can pass an empty string to the "replace" parameter.

Comment: The method that I worked out above with abernert seems to be working well for now, but I like this as well. I will keep it bookmarked for future use. Thank you.